# The authentication page for Fortinet access is not secure

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

When attempting to access my Fortinet firewall by entering its address in the web page's URL, I encounter a warning. How can I authorize its address or, perhaps, its SSL certificate to prevent the display of this warning page?

Best regards,[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a signed certificate on the Fortigate from a trusted certificate authority (CA), either public, or private and with its root certificate installed in your trust store.

A self-signed certificate from the Fortigate itself can only be used when the user hits *Advanced* → *Accept the risk and continue* (in Firefox).

If you use the certificate for a captive portal you'll need to obtain a public CA certificate, either commercial or by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , How i can install a signed certificate on the Fortigate from a trusted certificate authority (CA)?

Comment: Either you obtain one from a public CA or generate one on your CA server, import it on the Fortigate, and configure the web GUI to use it.

Comment: Yes, if your organization already has their own CA and uses/trusts it on your managed devices then you can simply create your own trusted certificates and install them on the Fortigate. If you do not already run your own CA then you probably want to buy a certificate from a publicly trusted CA or use Let's Encrypt for a free one.

Comment: Yes, I have created a certificate from Active Directory, and it was signed by Fortinet. However, I am still encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This article should cover the basics of how and why you would want to obtain and install an SSL certificate on your Fortinet Fortigate firewall:

https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-FortiGate-HTTPS-SSL-Certificate-Installation-PFX/ta-p/248447

You will need to purchase an SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority.

There are additional details on this page:
https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/7.0.9/administration-guide/825073/procuring-and-importing-a-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: "You will need to purchase an SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority."

OR you can get one for free: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: ... OR you can use your own CA to generate one or sign a CSR from the Fortigate.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea they added Let's Encrypt support on FortiOS. That is very helpful.
https://blogs.iuvotech.com/fortigate-fortios-7.0.1-auto-renewing-lets-encrypt-certificates

Comment: Yes, I have created a certificate from Active Directory, and it was signed by Fortinet. However, I am still encountering the same problem.

Comment: Please note that I am attempting to access the Fortinet web page from an internal, not a public address

Comment: That makes no difference. It will require a valid (trusted by your web browser) SSL certificate either way if you want to stop having the warning. If your computer still does not recognize the cert as trusted then your computer might not recognize your CA that issued the cert as trusted.